# InputStream appears to be loading twice

Tags: java, android, listview, inputstream

While working with the InputStream and coming back to the app after a long idle it appears to load a listview twice. The ParseQuery which uses basically the same code within my app does not. So I was wondering, without going into mounds and mounds of code if any of you have had similar issues with the InputStream and if so how did you correct it. By the way it doesn't do this if the app is only idle for a little while, by idle I mean if the user presses home and comes back to the app.

Screenshot (The top listview scrolls but the bottom one acts like a background):[image: The top listview scrolls but the bottom one acts like a background]

Here is the logcat upon a long idle:

```
06-14 21:23:02.373  16455-16458/com.parse.tcourt D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 3567K, 20% free 17314K/21447K, paused 12ms+15ms, total 82ms
06-14 21:23:04.866  16455-16458/com.parse.tcourt D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 5569K, 26% free 17983K/24071K, paused 12ms+7ms, total 80ms
06-14 21:23:07.949  16455-16458/com.parse.tcourt D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 6046K, 27% free 18214K/24775K, paused 5ms+7ms, total 127ms
06-14 21:23:10.622  16455-16458/com.parse.tcourt D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 5740K, 25% free 18728K/24967K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 137ms
```

Here is a logcat at startup:

```
06-14 21:30:00.990  17333-17333/com.parse.tcourt D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 585K, 10% free 15348K/16899K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
06-14 21:30:01.941  17333-17369/com.parse.tcourt I/Configurator﹕ ical4j.properties not found.
06-14 21:30:03.653  17333-17335/com.parse.tcourt D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 3620K, 19% free 17968K/22087K, paused 13ms+8ms, total 88ms
06-14 21:30:06.276  17333-17335/com.parse.tcourt D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 6237K, 28% free 17929K/24711K, paused 12ms+7ms, total 92ms
```

So it seems like its loading twice almost according to the logcats... Thanks